# Steak dropped in soapy dish water

Tags: food-safety

I accidentally dropped my steak in soapy dish water for a couple of seconds then rinsed it off and now I'm marinating it. Will it be safe to eat?

Comment: So, how was the steak?

Comment: If no answers for more than 48 hours, can we assume soapy steak did it's job?

Answer (score 50):

Dish soap won't kill you. You probably eat it, in traces, with every meal.

If you can't smell it or taste it, then no real harm done.

Comment: If the dish water were dirty, would the extra contaminants be a threat?

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoriaReinstateCMs unless the OP was planning to make steak tartare, no.

Comment: There are countries where it's typical to *not* rinse off dishes after cleaning them, so they get even more dish soap each time.  (I've heard Japan and the UK are this way),

Comment: As Stephie says, if you're cooking it, you're going to be cooking most of what's on it or saturating it also. It's obviously worse if you've dropped a steak in dirty water than not, however. Sinks in particular can be full of nasty germs.

Comment: If the dishwater was dirty enough to be a health hazard… why would you still be washing up in it?

Comment: @Joe As a life long UK resident this is the first I'm hearing this...

Comment: @user76129 - rinsing makes streaks & water spots. Not rinsing doesn't. Dish soap is designed that way. They're hardly going to 'build up soap' either way - that's just a preposterous idea ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin The only times I've had streaks and water spots is when you leave them to air dry.

Comment: So, we're down to personal preference. Rinsing is not necessary, neither is wiping them over with a tea-towel.

Comment: @Tetsujin If you don't rinse it wouldn't it taste soapy next time you eat with that dish since it has a ton of dish soap on it still?

Comment: 'a ton of soap' …? Well, approx one thimble-full to a large bowl of hot water, then allowed to drain until air-dry… Nope, can't say as it does.

Comment: @Onyz, I've drank water from a glass that wasn't sufficiently rinsed after washing, and it had a distinct bitter taste to it. Maybe if you never rinse your dishes, you simply can't taste it after a while, since you're used to it.

Comment: You guys are either just making this up now, or you're washing your dishes in 80% carbolic & battery acid. I've never heard anything so over-the-top.

Comment: @user76129 : The mention of Japan came from an NHK show [Home Sweet Tokyo](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/en/tv/homesweettokyo/), but when I went searching on my phone, I found mention that [it was a British thing](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,,-185700,00.html).  I guess I shouldn't have expanded that to 'UK'.  In the NHK show, I think they specifically mentioned that the dish soap was specially formulated to be safe, so I guess it's possible it's *not* safe everywhere.

Comment: The 'British thing' seems as contentious to Brits as it does to everybody else. Your 'reference' is just a bunch of comments in a newspaper. Each to his/her own. All it has served is to prolong a whole series of equally opinionated comments in here & doesn't help the answer one bit.

Answer (score 12):

I audit meat plants in the US and there is actually a thing called a meat wash sink. Red meat can legally be picked up off the floor and washed in a sink, but not with soap. I am agreeing this is pretty disgusting, but it is the case.  I have done a similar thing and been fine, but do not do this in a restaurant please, it is not OK there. As long as you remove the soap you're fine, but if the water had old food or other items, then, well, that is not the best idea.

Comment: If you tolerate this in a meat plant, why not in a restaurant?

Comment: @bobuhito Because then the cat is out of the bag. People in the modern day just freak out by the tiniest things.

Comment: @bobuhito Sink washed meat is the dollar store special. Paying for non-floor meat at a restaurant is an expectation.

Comment: Restaurant grill-station cook, after dropping a NY strip on the floor: "No germ could survive that fall." *rinse and serve.

Comment: Do you have any source on the regulations that allow steak rinsing?

Comment: @AlexD: Presumably it's allowed because water is Generally Recognized As Safe (Gras) in food, but soap isn't.

Comment: All I can tell you is every red meat plant I visit has a "meat wash sink" it is allowed under USDA regs.  I am not going to search the CFR to find that info for you sorry.

Comment: @AlexD I did look for guidance documents and found this reference in a USDA document.  https://www.fsis.usda.gov/shared/PDF/FSRE_SPS.pdf Again this is not me tolerating this is the USDA.  If you dont like it call Sonny Purdue the Commissioner of the USDA.